# can this be changed to a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I have code used when I get a response from an ajax request, similar to:

```
success: function(results) {
    if(results.locations){
        //do stuff here
    }else if(results.error){
        //do stuff here
    }else if(results.matched === 0){
        //do stuff here
    }else{
        // else do stuff here
    }
}
```

is it possible to change this to a switch statement? (results is a JSON array)

Comment: You're accessing different properties of the object and do not switch by different values of one, so no: This can't be converted to a switch statement in a meaningful way.

Comment: imho , interesting question. you can make something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/swZpK/2/

Comment: you can put those object values into an array perhaps then switch through that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in control of server side codes, you can add status property to results.

```
success: function(results) {
    switch (results.status) {
    case 'found_locations':
        // TO SOMETHING
        break;
    case 'error':
        // TO SOMETHING
        break;
    case 'no_results':
        // TO SOMETHING
        break;
    default:
        // TO SOMETHING
        break;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you are out of luck here.